# Triangle number program in C language?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want to make a simple triangle number program `1, 3, 6, 10,...` that is no more than `100`,I already made it. but there is little problem

lets take a look at my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int j=1 , k=1 , i=100 , status;

    while (k <= i){
        j = j + 1;
        k = k + j;
        while ( k < 100){

        printf (" %d\n",k);
        status = 1;
        break;
    }
    }
    if (status == 1){
    printf ("DONE!");
    }
}
```

output :

```
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
66
78
91
DONE !
```

From here, I have some problem :

1. I use two `While` Command,because when I only use one `While` the output will be bigger than `100` it will be `105`. So there is a way to simplify this by using one `while` command?
2. The Output does not start with number `1`, i want to make the program outputting like this :

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
66
78
91
DONE !
```

but in the end, The output always start with number `3`?

Comment: Please do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on the code you show.  When do you print the value of `k` in relation to your modification of `k`? What is the purpose of the inner loop and what does it really do?

Comment: Work backwards and you can see `k` is `j + 1` and `j` is `2`. `1 + 1 + 1` is...?

Comment: when i only use while `k <= i` and print the `k` value, the output value will be `105`, which is more than my desired value "Lower than `100`" , so i make second loop `k<100` and print the `k` value in the second loop and get result what i want and change the variabel `status` to `1`.  `if` function will check the `status` variable and if the `status` is `1` print `DONE!`

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is far too complicated. You only need one loop, a running sum and a variable to hold the next value to be added to sum.

Start the running sum at zero, then add 1 and print the sum, then add 2 and print the sum, then add 3 and print the sum... keep doing that until the sum gets above 100.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    int nextToAdd= 1;
    while(1)
    {
        sum += nextToAdd;
        ++nextToAdd;
        if (sum > 100) break;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or if you prefer do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum = 1;
    int nextToAdd = 1;
    do
    {
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        ++nextToAdd;
        sum += nextToAdd;
    } while(sum <= 100);
    return 0;
}
```

or if you prefer a for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum = 1;
    for (int nextToAdd = 2; sum <= 100; ++nextToAdd)
    {
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        sum += nextToAdd;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you use only one while , when `k=91` so `k<=100` and the condition of `while`is true and so you will enter while and `k` will become `105` and you will print it. so you need one `if` before `printf` to check `if(k<100)`.

also here if you initialized `k=0` and replace `k+=j` and with `j++` you will also print `1`.

look:

```
int main()
{
    int k = 1, j = 2, i = 100;
    while (k <= i) {
        printf("%d\n", k);
        k += j;
        j++;
    }
    printf("DONE!");
}
```

Comment: why `k` variabel start from `0`?

Comment: @Proust this is matter algorithm you choose to solve this question.in this algorithm you should use `k=0` ,otherwise you will get wrong answer in this soultion